# Java Serialization/De-SerializationTry Catch within a Try

Tags: java, serialization, try-catch, outputstream, data-transfer-objects

It's my first time posting on this site and I am trying to write a program that implements Server-Client connection via sockets using a transfer object.

Within the server side when I'm de-serializing an object if any exception happens I want to send that object back telling the client that there was a failure which the client then disconnects.

My resolve so far was to write an object inside the catch block surrounding with another try catch block; catch being empty.

Is this a good practice? Is there a cleaner solution to this? Is the way to let the client know without writing the object?

Code:

```
try {
    if (transferObject.getMessage().equals("insert")){
       dao = new DAO();
       dao.insertToDB(transferObject.getObject();
       transferObject.setMessage("success");
       }
    else if (transferObject.getMessage().equals("disconnect")) {
       transferObject = new TransferObject("disconnect");//contructor sets object to null.
       }
    out.writeObject(transferObject);
    out.flush();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      transferObject = new TransferObject("failure");
      try {
           out.writeObject(transferObject);
           out.flush();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        //nothing here
      }
    }
```

Comment: No. What happens if you get an exception handling the exception? 'Nothing' is not an adequate response.

Comment: *I'm de-serializing an object if any exception happens I want to send that object back* if there is an exception, you won't get any deserialized object, so you can't send it back.

Comment: How could I send a transferobject (with the message "failure" and object null) back letting the client know so that the client could handle that message and shut down accordingly?

Comment: The way you did it. Except you could indent your code, and extract the block inside the catch block to a method

Comment: But what if I get an exception while handling that exception? Should I just print out a message to console?

Comment: _"Should I just print out a message to console"_ -- What you do at that point depends on the environment in which your code is running.  If it's a command-line program then console output might be appropriate. For a background server you should already have a logging framework in place.  Without a lot more information about your environment we cannot answer the question, and in any case the question means you haven't defined your _requirements_ sufficiently.  It's up to you (well, your users/clients) to decide what they want to happen in that case.

Comment: You should not catch it and just let your method throw. If you don't know how to handle an exception at some point, then maybe that's not the point to handle it. Usually programs have a high-level exception handler for exceptions that bubbled up the stack, most frameworks do that. Also beware of the catch(Exception e) antipattern; on the first catch, you should only catch the serialization exception. If you just catch any exception, you will be catching also OutOfMemoryException or StackOverflowException, which you should never catch, your program should actually fail on those.

Comment: This is an example from my college assignment that I wrote but I wasn't sure what it meant in the instructions by "If any exceptions occur, send a new transfer object with the message of failure, and null the object within the transfer object." I'm unable to contact my prof atm due to my college going on strike.

Comment: Well, if your statement clearly stated catching any exception, go with it, but it is a terrible practice in real life. Anyway, from the problem statement, I think you are not supposed to send back the same transfer object you received. I think it is asking you to send a transfer object that contains a message error, which could be something like "Error processing your request. Cause: " + e.getMessage(). As for the "null the object within the tranfer object, I have no idea what it means.

Comment: The constructor of TransferObject's parameter is the string to set the message. Within that constructor, it also sets the object within to null.

Comment: I think you should read the [Java Tutorial on Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: I understand how Exceptions work, I was just wondering if there was a better way of doing what I was doing.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it correctly. One thing I can suggest is to move `writeObject()` and `flush()` from outside the first `try{}` (either outside the block, or into the `finally` clause).

```
try
{
    if (transferObject.getMessage().equals("insert"))
    {
        dao = new DAO();
        dao.insertToDB(transferObject.getObject();
        transferObject.setMessage("success");
    }
    else if (transferObject.getMessage().equals("disconnect")) 
    {
        transferObject = new TransferObject("disconnect"); //constructor sets object to null
    }

} 
catch(Exception e) 
{
    transferObject = new TransferObject("failure");
}  
finally
{
    out.writeObject(transferObject);
    out.flush();
}
```

Comment: Finally closes all my steams and connection which is when the client disconnects.